# How can I aggregate on multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

Now i have some data looks like below :

```
    song_id                             artist_id                     0 days 1 days 2 days  
1   0919b5ed4ce2649f61bcc6c21fadab12    0c80008b0a28d356026f4b1097041689    0   0   0
2   8a0777df37bf6a0f3384d63a47d4d21b    0c80008b0a28d356026f4b1097041689    0   1   0
3   b61bc45712ee40c3f4a37dd4d063ad52    0c80008b0a28d356026f4b1097041689    0   0   0
4   a2fbe29da3a760d7467b8a7b3247a9c8    0c80008b0a28d356026f4b1097041689    0   0   1
5   b5e92cb9ff2126189c19305cf148b25d    0c80008b0a28d356026f4b1097041689    0   0   0
```

And I want to group them by artist_id and aggregate the sum on `0 days` , `1 days` and `2 days` , and get result like that .

```
        artist_id                      0 days 1 days 2 days
0       0c80008b0a28d356026f4b1097041689    0   1   1
```

I tried

```
df.groupby('artist_id').sum()
```

But it raise an error .

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timedelta' with type 'str'
```

`df.info` shows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10842 entries, 0 to 10841
Columns: 185 entries, song_id to 182 days 00:00:00
dtypes: float64(183), object(2)
memory usage: 15.4+ MB
```

How can I solve it using pandas's way ?

Any help is welcomed .

Comment: What was error? For me it works very well.

Comment: What does `df.info()` show, if you have non-numeric dtypes then `sum` will fail

Comment: @jezrael  I have updated the question. Thanks for commenting .

Comment: @EdChum I have updated the question. Thanks for commenting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , the `sum()` function failed because there are `timedelta` in columns and they can't be aggregated .

Comment: :) I understand, so I add next possible solution with `astype`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone .

After applying

```
df.columns = map(str,df.columns)
```

The step

```
df.groupby('artist_id').sum()
```

works .